# Pimcore 4 classmap

Tags: php, pimcore

I am migrating a website from Pimcore 3 to 4 (RC1) and I am struggling with the class mappings. Before this was done with a file `website/var/config/classmap.xml` in the new version there is a file in `website/config/classmap.php` (different directory and type). I followed the example, and cleared the cache several times (used to be required for Pimcore 3) but it has no effect, the class mappings are not applied. I cannot find any documentation on how to do it in Pimcore 4. The XML used to have a link to documentation in it, that is no longer the case.

This is my classmap.php:

```
return [
    "Object\\Tag" => "Website\\Model\\Tag",
    "Object\\Tag\\List" => "Website\\Model\\Tag\\Listing",

    "Object\\News" => "Website\\Model\\News",
    "Object\\News\\List" => "Website\\Model\\News\\Listing",

    "Object\\Column" => "Website\\Model\\Column",
    "Object\\Column\\List" => "Website\\Model\\Column\\Listing",

    "Object\\Project" => "Website\\Model\\Project",
    "Object\\Project\\List" => "Website\\Model\\Project\\Listing",

    "Object\\Employee" => "Website\\Model\\Employee",
    "Object\\Employee\\List" => "Website\\Model\\Employee\\Listing",
];
```

I tried digging around the code in `pimcore/config/startup.php` I found this:

```
// register class map loader => speed
$autoloaderClassMapFiles = array(
    PIMCORE_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY . "/autoload-classmap.php",
    PIMCORE_PATH . "/config/autoload-classmap.php"
);
```

I tried renaming the files to `autoload-classmap.php` but that did not work either.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Your classmap.php seems to be OK. Just to be sure, do you have an open php tag in that file? (<?php) 
I have classmap.php in /website/var/config but /website/config should work too.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your reply. Yes there is a PHP-opening tag, I just realized that the problem may be because of the model itself. I have the following code in website/models/Website/News.php 

`<?php

namespace Website;
use Pimcore\Model\Object; 

class News extends Object\News {
}

namespace Website\News;
class Listing extends \Pimcore\Model\Object\News\Listing {

}
`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what seems to be the problem. First of all your namespace should be: `namespace Website\Model;` and the file should be saved in /website/lib/Website/Model/.